# How connect .sql file to Crystal Report?

Tags: mysql, sql, crystal-reports

How connect .sql file to Crystal Report?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible. You should open the .sql file and see what it contains.

Scenario:

1. It's just an sql query, in that case you can just copy paste it to use in your report after selecting the db it should query.
2. It has create tables and insert data. This would require you to create the database first in your database server. Then you can add the newly create db to your project

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you can show me some video haw to do?